# how to call a function within class in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new to objective c programming I want to call a function within anothor method please give me idea.

```
-(void) grabRSSFeed:(NSString *)blogAddress {

    // Initialize the blogEntries MutableArray that we declared in the header
    myBlogEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    // Convert the supplied URL string into a usable URL object
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: blogAddress];

    // Create a new rssParser object based on the TouchXML "CXMLDocument" class, this is the
    // object that actually grabs and processes the RSS data
    CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

    // Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
    NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

    // Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
    resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//item" error:nil];

    // Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data
    for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

        // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries
        NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        // Create a counter variable as type "int"
        int counter;

        // Loop through the children of the current  node
        for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

            // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
            [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];

        }       
        // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
        [myBlogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];

    }  
}
```

**want to call above function in Babes Method**

```
    -(IBAction)babes
{   
    myview.hidden = FALSE;

    [myview startAnimating];



    feedurl = @"http://www.luxury.net/feed/rss/babes.xml";
    //want to call it here.....

    [self performSelector:@selector(moveAlert:) withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.7f];

}
```

but its not working please help me out thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the beginner documentation, start here: [Learning Obj-C](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594)

For your problem specifically, try this:

```
NSString* aBlogAdress = @"http://anAdress.com";
[self grabRSSFeed:aBlogAddress];
```

Comment: To be picky, your second line is a typo -- should be "aBlogAddress", not "blogAddress". Otherwise, 100% agreed.

Answer (score 1):

You use `self` just as you are doing already, but you have to supply the argument correctly.

```
[self grabRSSFeed:@"http://someurl.com"];
```

The blogAddress is an NSString that you must supply somehow. For example, if you have a text view called textViewRSSFeed in your app, you would supply the value for that field.

```
[self grabRSSFeed:textViewRSSFeed.text];
```

Comment: Greensource is spot on -- you need to go RTFM. Your problem is solved with [self grabRSSFeed:feedurl]; though, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void)grabRssFeed:(NSString *)str
    {



    }


-(void)ViewDidLoad
  {
  NSString *Str=@"www.anyUrl.com";

  [Self grabRssFeed:Str];

   }
```